# Can a company claim they acted in good faith in this situation?

Tags: contract-law, european-union

Let's assume that Hacker Corp. offers a penetration testing service to other businesses, and ACME Corp. contacts Hacker Corp. to conduct a penetration test for some internal testing.

Hacker Corp. requires ACME Corp. to sign a "Permission to Attack" document, which outlines that Hacker Corp. is allowed to attack a specific system of ACME Corp. during a specified timeframe in a specified way.

Due to internal turmoil in ACME Corp., the Permission to Attack document never gets signed by the people with the powers to sign it, and instead a low-level IT employee in ACME Corp. signs instead. During the penetration test, a machine in ACME Corp.'s infrastructure fails and causes an outage, which costs ACME Corp. millions of dollars. This failure was not foreseeable and not caused by negligence.

ACME Corp. now wishes to sue Hacker Corp. for damages, claiming they were attacking ACME Corp. without a valid Permission to Attack. Can Hacker Corp. claim that they acted in good faith, believing that the Permission to Attack was granted by someone from within the company who was allowed to grant such a permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can Hacker Corp. claim that they acted in good faith, believing that the Permission to Attack was granted by someone from within the company who was allowed to grant such a permission?

Unless ACME proves that Hacker knew or should have known that ACME's low-level employee had no authority to make the decision on behalf of ACME, Hacker ought to prevail on the basis that it *performed* the contract. There is no indication in your description that Hacker targeted other system(s) than the one(s) specified or that it departed from the agreed conditions. Therefore, there is no sign of Hacker breaching the *implied covenant of good faith*.

ACME's evidently poor management (i.e., the turmoil, the delay for signing or denying permission, its low-level employee's opportunity to make sensitive decisions, the company's failure to withdraw the authorization or to take precautions) is not Hacker's fault.

Comment: In my hypothetical scenario, Hacker Corp. only attacked the systems that were outlined in all previous conversations with ACME Corp. So I *assume* ACME have to deal with the damages done.

Comment: Such documents usually contain a provision in which the signer warrants that s/he has authority to sign on behalf of the company. Hacker Corp is entitled to rely on such a provision unless hey knew or had reason to know that they should not have.

Comment: I think you've reached the right outcome, but the wrong way. If the company is alleging there was no contract to begin with, it isn't raising a contract claim, and performance of the contract therefore can't be the basis for Hacker to prevail. Instead, Hacker should assert apparent-authority under agency theory, claiming that it reasonably believed the IT grunt had authority to enter into the contract. It could then use that contract to argue that it had Acme's *consent* to conduct its test, defeating whatever negligence or intentional-tort claims Acme has raised.

Comment: Of course, either analysis relies on common-law principles, which may not even be relevant, given the EU tag.

Comment: @bdb484 "*I think you've reached the right outcome, but the wrong way. If the company is alleging there was no contract to begin with*". ACME cannot simply allege that. The document with the employee's signature evidences ACME's *acceptance* of Hacker's *offer*. Hence the formation of a contract. ACME would need to present evidence that outweighs the probatory value of the signed document.

Comment: Quite incorrect. Acme is writing the complaint, so it gets to allege basically whatever it wants, and then it bears the burden of proving the truth of its allegations.

Comment: It would probably unfold like this: Acme alleges the absence of an agreement. Acme CEO testifies at deposition that there was no consent. Hacker impeaches CEO with the signed PTA. Acme counters by saying the employee was not authorized to sign. Now you're left with a question as to whether there was implied agency. The apparent-authority theory I discussed above provides the answer.

Comment: @bdb484 "*it gets to allege basically whatever it wants*". That is akin to the typical "*sure you can sue, but you would lose*", and as such it is pointless. "*Now you're left with a question as to whether there was implied agency*". That is exactly why my answer starts with "*[...] whether Hacker knew or should have known that ACME's low-level employee had the authority to make the decision on behalf of ACME*".

Comment: It's not really the same thing at all. The question of whether there's a valid contract boils down to a factual dispute over whether Hacker reasonably believed the IT grunt had authority to sign on behalf of the country. If they had policies in place to prevent Hacker from coming to that conclusion, but those policies were unknowingly violated due to the "internal turmoil" OP mentioned, Acme would have a good faith basis for making its allegation.

Comment: @bdb484 You keep trying to make a distinction only to end up paraphrasing the answer. The question of "*whether Hacker reasonably believed*" is implicit in the issue of "*whether Hacker knew or should have known*". Hacker cannot be expected to know ACME's undisclosed policies, let alone to the extent that the signed document supports Hacker's understanding that it is ok to proceed with the pentest. Furthermore, violating a policy *unknowingly* weakens ACME's argument of breach of good faith. Unless ACME proves what I mentioned, the only viable claim ACME would have is against its own employee.

Comment: Yes -- as I said, I agree with your final conclusion, even if I disagree with the reasoning; Hacker can't use a contract defense to avoid liability on a tort claim.

Comment: @bdb484 "*Hacker can't use a contract defense*". Yes it can because the pentest was performed pursuant to a contract/agreement with ACME as evidenced by the signed document. By contrast, ACME cannot establish a tort claim merely by pretending there was no contract between them. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123083/discussion-between-inaki-viggers-and-bdb484).

Comment: I'm probably just not wording this clearly enough. When I say Hacker "can't use a contract defense," I don't mean it can't use the contract to defend itself; I agree with you that it should. Instead, I'm saying that because Acme is raising a tort claim rather than a contract claim, Hacker can't defend itself by invoking "performance," which is a defense to a contract claim; it must instead characterize its defense as "consent," which is a defense to a tort claim.

Comment: With Rule 8 in mind, you can see how your imprecision would become fatal: if you filed an answer raising the contract defense of performance, but omitted the tort defense of consent, Hacker would be unable to rely on either defense and would likely lose the entire case.

Comment: @bdb484 There is no imprecision. *Consent* is implicit in the contract/agreement. By premising on the latter, more so as evidenced by the signed document, Hacker would "*fairly respond to the **substance** of the allegation*", [FRCP 8(b)(2)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_8) (emphasis added). The notion that the defense of *consent* first (or at all) has to be raised explicitly lest Hacker "lose the entire case" is purely ritualistic, something which courts repeatedly purport to avoid. But again, please use the chat.

Comment: I can see how you might read Rule 8 that way, but you're missing the operative language. I see that you are very defensive about this answer, though, so I'll let you have it.

Comment: @bdb484 "*I can see how you might read Rule 8 that way, but you're missing the operative language*". Don't get creative. I quoted the *statutory* language verbatim. Anyone can corroborate that. "*you are very defensive about this answer, though, so I'll let you have it*". I'm just not letting you obfuscate also here with "corrections" which are nothing but fictitious distinctions. One has to assume that judges are dumb enough to read Hacker's performance argument and yet fail to grasp the [ACME's] consent that is inherent to the contract.

Comment: No one's denying that you quoted a part of the rule, friend. I'm just saying you're quoting the wrong part. It's an easy mistake when you don't know American civil procedure, so it's not anything you need to be defensive about it. You got pretty close to right the answer without any real education in the law, and that's pretty good.